# Roots of a minimal polynomial over a splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm working on various problem to prepare for an upcoming exam. One problem that I've been having issues with is as follows:

> Let $E=F[\alpha]$ and let $f = \min_F(\alpha)$. Then, $|E : F|_{sep}$ is the number of different roots $f$ has in some (any) splitting field for $f$ over $F$.

I was working with a group of people in my study group, and we couldn't come up with much. They came up with a sketchy proof that involved some hand-waiving, and I am not satisfied with it.

Can anyone offer any suggestions to help me prove this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $|E:F|_{sep}$ is the number of $F$-homomorphisms $E \to F^{alg}$. Since $E=F[\alpha] \cong F[X]/(f)$, using the universal properties of quotients and polynomial algebras, such a homomorphism is the same as giving a root $\beta$ of $f$ in $F^{alg}$. More concretely, $\beta$ is the image of $X$, and in general $\overline{g(X)}$ is mapped to $g(\beta)$, where well-definedness means $f(\beta)=0$. It follows that $|E:F|_{sep}$ is the number of different roots of $f$ in $F^{alg}$. Of course this equals the number of different roots of $f$ in any splitting field of $f$, because each such splitting field can be embedded in $F^{alg}$.